# NextJS Application crash from RAM overflow

Tags: typescript, next.js, backend, multer, ram

Good time of day. Faced with the task of writing an application in the likeness of the Dropmefiles service, for an internal corporate network. I chose NextJS to implement client and server functionality for the sake of simplicity of deployment in a closed network, since there is no Internet access there, etc. Sending files is done by multi-part form using axios.
The problems started at the stage of implementing the server functionality. In the end, using next-connect, Multer and ts-ignore in one place, files are successfully saved, but when writing large files, an unthinkable amount of RAM is consumed, which is approximately equal to the file size. Having limited the amount of RAM with the help of a docker container, up to 2 Gigabytes, it began to crash out without an error at all, reaching the RAM limit.
I hope someone will be able to give good advice on this problem.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import multer from "multer";
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./uploads",
    filename(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, file.originalname);
    },
  }),
});

const uploadMiddleware = upload.single("file");
const router = createRouter<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>();

//@ts-ignore
router.use(uploadMiddleware);

router.post(async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ data: "Success" });
});
export default router.handler();
```